# Image is not responsive after giving width 100% in css

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="Slider">
    <img class="img1" src="Images/pic04.jpg" ></img>
</div>
```

In above div tag image is not becoming responsive though i gave width=100%; in css
below is whole css

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-size: 13pt;
    line-height: 1.75em;
    letter-spacing: 0.015em;
    font-family:Comic Sans, Comic Sans MS, cursive;
}
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#wrapper {
    border:1px solid;
    width:1100px;
    margin:auto;
}
#Slider {
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}
.img1 {
    width:100%;
}
```

In above #wrapper is container of Html page and slider is the div where i want to make image responsive.when i am changing size of my browser window image is not responsive.

Comment: Can u please make JSfiddle?

Comment: It's working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/178/ . Resize the result container and the image adjust itself accordingly

Comment: Most likely your parent div `Slider` is not set to the width you are expecting.

Comment: @KamleshKushwaha: it is not working in System should i post whole Html file

Comment: Post the relevant html and css which might be affecting the css of div

Answer (score 0):

`width:100%` means it takes the `width of wrapper` not the browser. when you re-size the browser the `wrapper` width will not `re-size to browser size`. so change the size of the `wrapper` using `media-queries` on re-size of window. so the image automatically re-sizes.

```
<!-- CSS media query on a link element -->
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 600px)" href="example.css" />

<!-- CSS media query within a example.css -->

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #wrapper{
    width: 700px;
  }
}
```

[Media-Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)